# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Webapi simple authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I would like to secure certain api's in dotnet core.
There is no need for roles. I only need to allow or disallow.
To check if a user is allowed I use Active Directory with a Novell nuget [library](https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard). This part already works.

To secure the api I just add the **Authorize** attribute on the method.

At the moment I use a http header to pass username and password. (base64 encoded).

How do I combine the AD check with the Authorize attribute?

I've seen AddIdentity / AddAuthentication / AddAuthorization / Claims / JWT / ... but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [Thinktecture IdentityServer](https://github.com/identityserver) Get's the jobe done

you will also find a lot of examples and samples that you can refer to.

Comment: To add to this solution, AD integration:  http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html

Comment: thanks for the reference for completion sake :) @Schwarzie2478